# Does Boursin cheese always contain garlic?

Tags: cheese, spices, garlic, cream-cheese

Does French [Boursin cheese](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boursin_cheese) always contain garlic?

Comment: Why was my question downvoted? If I made a mistake, please let me know so I can learn from it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 'standard' Boursin flavour is garlic and herbs, which I would imagine would *have* to contain garlic, or they'd be in trouble for false advertising. However, these days they also produce other flavours like black pepper and chive and shallot. A cursory glance at the ingredients on [their website](http://www.boursin.co.uk/Our-Cheese/Boursin-R-150g) shows no garlic in these latter two.